# Image from camera not set to ImageView

Tags: android

Image taken from a camera is not set even though the Code I'm using is from the android developer website. Please help. I don't get what I'm supposed to do. Sometimes, the OnActivityResult method isn't called either. Here is the code I am using:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Created: " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        galleryAddPic();
        return image;
    }


    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void setPic() {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
//        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
//        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();
//
//        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
//        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
//        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
//        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
//        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
//
//        // Determine how much to scale down the image
//        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
//
//        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
//        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
//        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
//        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d("", "onActivityResult: "+mCurrentPhotoPath);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check if your mCurrentPhotoPath is the same at both times i.e before you launch the camera app and after you return from camera app.

Comment: You are using REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO while starting activity and REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE in onActivityResult. I think they both should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you start an activity for result, the request code identifies the request. So if you started camera activity with request code, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO then you must use the same request code in activity result i.e.

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
    Log.d("", "onActivityResult: "+mCurrentPhotoPath);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Since you want to decodeFile, your `mCurrentPhotoPath` must be absolute file path and not uri.So remove "file:" from `mCurrentPhotoPath`

**createImageFile**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Created: " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        galleryAddPic();
        return image;
    }
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Thanks man. Any idea what to do now that the bitmap returns null? THe photopath is the same in both the places

Comment: Check if picture taken by the camera is available at the location `Pictures` folder on your android device..

Comment: try adding permission `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your manifest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96957/discussion-between-sam24-and-fabin-paul).